# Convert multiple year columns into single year column (tidy format) in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My data set is in form of:

[image]

I want to convert it into :

[image]

How can I do it in Python using pandas?

**It solved thanks and appreciate your time to help!!! +1 for all**

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['name'], value_vars=['2016', '2017', '2018',"2019"],var_name='year', value_name='value').sort_values('name')
```

Output:

```
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|    | name  | year  | value |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
| 0  | abc   | 2016  |     1 |
| 2  | abc   | 2017  |     2 |
| 4  | abc   | 2018  |     5 |
| 6  | abc   | 2019  |     9 |
| 1  | def   | 2016  |     5 |
| 3  | def   | 2017  |     8 |
| 5  | def   | 2018  |     8 |
| 7  | def   | 2019  |     4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) without specifying `value_vars`

> If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as id_vars.

```py
df.melt(id_vars='name', var_name='year').sort_values('name')

  name  year  value
0  abc  2016      1
2  abc  2017      2
4  abc  2018      5
6  abc  2019      9
1  def  2016      5
3  def  2017      8
5  def  2018      8
7  def  2019      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
a = df.columns[1:]
df.melt(id_vars='name',value_vars = a,var_name='year').sort_values('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

- [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) is the easiest approach to convert your dataframe to a [tidy format](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

  - Unpivot a DataFrame from wide format to long format, optionally leaving identifier variables set.
- An alternate approach is [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long)

  - Wide panel to long format. Less flexible but more user-friendly than melt.

```py
import pandas as pd

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['abc', 'def'],
                   '2016': [1, 5],
                   '2017': [2, 8],
                   '2018': [5, 8],
                   '2019': [9, 4]})

name  2016  2017  2018  2019
 abc     1     2     5     9
 def     5     8     8     4

# melt df
df_melt = df.melt(id_vars='name', value_vars=['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019'])

name variable  value
 abc     2016      1
 def     2016      5
 abc     2017      2
 def     2017      8
 abc     2018      5
 def     2018      8
 abc     2019      9
 def     2019      4
```